# C# DataTable with a ushort field as parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datatable, user-defined-types, table-valued-parameters

I have a store procedure in SQL Server that has as a parameter a table value type.

Table valued type is the following:

```
CREATE TYPE [Serveis].[tblType_DispensadorBebidas_Abonados] AS TABLE 
(
    [ID] [varchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [Field1] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Field2] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
```

Then the stored procedure takes this table valued type as parameter:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddData] 
    @DataTable MytableValuedType READONLY
```

From C# I create a DataTable as below:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string)).SetOrdinal(0);           
dt.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(ushort)).SetOrdinal(1);
dt.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(ushort)).SetOrdinal(2);
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime)).SetOrdinal(3);

dt.Rows.Add(this.ID,this.Field1,this.Field2,this.Date);
```

In C# data types are:

- ID string
- Field1 ushort
- Field2 ushort
- Date DateTime

and then I create a SQL Parameter:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@DataTable";
param.Value = dt;
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Add it using command.Parameters.Add(param)

and finally I call ExecuteNonQuery.

It throws the error (translated from spanish):

```
Column type 'Field1' not allowed. The type is "'UInt16'".
```

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smallint` in SQL Server is signed. You will need to use a matching signed data type (i.e. `short`) in your C# code. This should be as simple as:

```
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string)).SetOrdinal(0);           
    dt.Columns.Add("Field1", typeof(short)).SetOrdinal(1);
    dt.Columns.Add("Field2", typeof(short)).SetOrdinal(2);
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime)).SetOrdinal(3);
```